# Mistake in echo

Tags: php, echo

Could someone tell me what fails in the following line:

```
echo '<div id="login"><div id="centrar_app"><label>Success. Created account. <a href='login_app.php'>Log In</a></label></div></div>';
```

I know it must be a tiny stupid error, but I don't get it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Well, the screen shows nothing (white page) when the php page is loaded

Comment: See [this reference answer on how to find your error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851). Also note that the code formatting here, and any decent editor, gives a big clue about where in the string the problem is.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 2. Which one do you recommend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing single quotes and double quotes. `href='login_app.php'` change to `href="login_app.php"`

Try this,

```
  echo '<div id="login"><div id="centrar_app"><label>Success. Created account. <a href="login_app.php">Log In</a></label></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this code, its just mistake of single quote**(')** and double quote**(")**

```
echo '<div id="login"><div id="centrar_app"><label>Success. Created account. <a href="login_app.php">Log In</a></label></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="login"><div id="centrar_app"><label>Success. Created account. <a href="login_app.php">Log In</a></label></div></div>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing double quote with single quote, use below:-

```
 echo '<div id="login"><div id="centrar_app"><label>Success. Created account. <a href="login_app.php">Log In</a></label></div></div>';
```

You can use your current script with the php variable like below:-

```
$login_url='login_app.php';

echo '<div id="login"><div id="centrar_app"><label>Success. Created account. <a href='.$login_url.'>Log In</a></label></div></div>';
```